# Ajax Upload An Image Where The File Is Set in LocalStorage

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, xmlhttprequest, local-storage

This question has been edited to reflect my attempts at using a blobs and a binary string.

I was reading the following documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) and got the following script to work:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("nationname", "my_nation");
formData.append("localid", "Ql5SvPgB2Aq9w");

// HTML file input user's choice...
formData.append("file", $("input[name='file']")[0].files[0]);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "/cgi-bin/upload.cgi");
request.send(formData);
```

So again, the above worked. I was able to upload my image through ajax using this script. My problem is, I want to be able to upload a flag from any page under this domain (I'm building a Chrome extension for an interactive browser game) and therefore I can't use `$("input[name='file']")[0].files[0]` for the file object all the time because the form won't be in front of me, I won't be interacting with the form, I'll be on another page. I wanted to use localStorage to store the file object, and then call it from localStorage, append it to the form, and send the ajax request.

I set it in localStorage using the following code:

```
 $("input[value='Set Puppet']").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var toRemove = $(this);
    var binary = $("input[type='file']")[0].files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var caata = "";
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        caata = reader.result;
        var puppet = {
            email: $("input[id='puppet_email']").val(),
            password: $("input[id='password']").val(),
            flag: caata
        };
        localStorage.setItem("puppet", JSON.stringify(puppet));
        toRemove.parent().remove();
        $("#setSuccess").text("Puppet Set, Hit The P Key To Create Your Puppets!");
    }
    var daata = reader.readAsBinaryString(binary);
    });
```

So to be clear, that is only called once. For the purposes of setting up the localStorage `puppet.flag`, which contains the file object. But when I do this:

```
var uploadFlag = function () {
    if (puppet.flag.length > 0) {
        var pattern = /"flag":"(.[A-Z]\w+)/g;
        var filetype = pattern.exec(localStorage.puppet);
        filetypes = "image/" + filetype[1].toLowerCase();
        console.log(filetypes);

        function BinarytoBlob(binary) {
            binarydata = new Uint8Array(binary.length);
            for (var x = 0; x < binary.length; x++) {
                binarydata[x] = binary.charCodeAt(x);
            }
            return new Blob([binarydata], {
                type: filetypes
            });
        }
        var blob = BinarytoBlob(puppet.flag);
        console.log(blob);
        $.get("http://www.nationstates.net/page=upload_flag", function (data) {
            var flagForm = new FormData();
            flagForm.append("nationname", name.toLowerCase());
            flagForm.append("localid", $(data).find("input[name='localid']").val());
            flagForm.append("file", blob);
            var flagUpload = new XMLHttpRequest();
            flagUpload.open("POST", "/cgi-bin/upload.cgi");
            flagUpload.send(flagForm);
        });
    }
};
```

It doesn't work. I see the ajax request go to /cgi-bin/upload.cgi but something wrong happens because I get redirected away from a success page and it tells me the file is not a valid image file, even though I select a PNG and see it is a PNG in the binary string.

I hope I have explained adequately. Please advise.

Comment: You cannot serialize a File object into a string and therefore cannot store it in localStorage

Comment: You can convert it to a data uri though

Comment: @Musa apparently data uris are not supported by the website in question, so I tried it as a binary string, but that doesn't work either! :(

Answer (score 0):

Strings in JavaScript aren't "binary", in the sense that they can't store any arbitrary data, the `readAsBinaryString` doesn't really mean what you think it does. Since localstorage only holds strings you'll have to convert the file to a string then convert it back when you need to send it. You can accomplish this

- Convert to string for storage with `readAsBinaryString`
- Convert from string to binary array

  ```
  binarydata = new Uint8Array(stringdata.length);
  for (var x = 0; x < byteArray.length; x++){
      binarydata[x] = stringdata.charCodeAt(x);
  }
  var blob = new Blob([binarydata ], {type: what_ever_type_this_file_was});
  ```
- upload the blob

Comment: I still get the error message from the server that I am uploading to.

"Not A Valid Image File"

Comment: @LSD note that `BinarytoBlob` isn't returning anything

Comment: I will update my code to show you what I have now, where it does return something.

Comment: where do you call `uploadFlag `, where do you retrieve the data from local storeage?

Comment: I call it using a keybind, on a keypress I call it. I know it is being called.